# How can I recover a BigQuery table with too many partitions?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to recover a table that was deleted from BigQuery, but it has more partitions than the maximum allowed.

I'm attempting to use the following command, which works for deleted tables in general:

```
bq cp datasetname.tablename@1694709871000 datasetname.temp
```

For one table, I get this error message:

```
BigQuery error in cp operation: Error processing job '...': Resources
exceeded during query execution: 16471 partitions will be copied to
the table datasetname.temp, which exceeds the limit 4000 for the number
of partitions in the table.
```

I didn't originally set up this table but apparently it was partitioned hourly. Anyway, I need to recover it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official method for partially recovering a BigQuery table, so your issue is quite complex. I recommend contacting customer support for assistance, as they may be able to temporarily increase the partition limit to facilitate data recovery.
Best,